# Is it possible to make a DataTable as a AutoCompleteSource in a TextBox? (C#)

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make a DataTable as a AutoCompleteSource in a TextBox? (C#)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jared is correct - you can't bind directly without doing some manipulation.  Here's an example of using the LINQ DataSet extensions to retrieve a field as the autocomplete source:

```
DataTable dtPosts = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StackOverflow"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 100 Id, Title, Body, CreationDate FROM Posts WHERE Title IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Id", conn))
    {
        adapt.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
        adapt.Fill(dtPosts);
    }
}

//use LINQ method syntax to pull the Title field from a DT into a string array...
string[] postSource = dtPosts
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("Title"))
                    .ToArray();

var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(postSource);
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... but it seems so complicated for me to understand your code... I'm just new to programming and I choose C# language to study. I don't know yet using LINQ.

Comment: @DavidHoerster How would you then know which one has been chosen from the string array?

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, you'll want to read your datatable into an [`AutoCompleteStringCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kek20dbk.aspx).

You could do something like this ([from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/705b7a5d-b018-48e5-8c7d-b0d4f79ec2d3)):

```
private AutoCompleteStringCollection GetAutoSourceCollectionFromTable(DataTable table)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection autoSourceCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        autoSourceCollection.Add(row[0]); //assuming required data is in first column
    }

    return autoSourceCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already know your answer, but to someone who comes to this question, the answer is no, if you are in doubt, see the supported options for [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When it comes to AutoComplete custom data in Winforms, we use the [AutoCompleteCustomSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option which can only get or set an [AutoCompleteStringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Now, you can populate a **DataTable** by fetching records from a database with your desired query and method, and then you can add these records to the StringCollection by iterating through the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) elements of the **DataTable**. Here's an easy example made by [Leandro Tuttini](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-autocomplete-combobox-o-textbox.html):

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = LoadAutoComplete(); //this method is below
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;


public static AutoCompleteStringCollection LoadAutoComplete()
{
   DataTable dt = LoadDataTable(); //suppose this method returns a DataTable with fetched records from database.
   AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
      stringCol.Add(Convert.ToString(row[0]));
   }
   return stringCol; //return the string collection with added records
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Here is an example using a typed dataset and two textboxes ([source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/SQLAutoCompleteList.aspx)...scroll past the large images at the top to get to the code)

```
For Each store As StoreDataSet.StoreRow In StoreDataSet.Store
    If store.StoreID.StartsWith("0") Then
        StoreIDTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(store.StoreID.TrimStart("0"))
    End If
    StoreIDTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(store.StoreID)
    StoreNameTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(store.StoreName)
Next store
```