# Text Box custom source as data table

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set a custom source for my Text Box for the suggest option.
I've got so far to this.

```
 private void Input_Box_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     sc.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select MoM_ID from dbo.MoM_Form ORDER BY MoM_ID ASC", sc);
     SqlDataReader R_1;

     R_1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     DataTable dt_1 = new DataTable();
     dt_1.Columns.Add("MoM_ID", typeof(string));
     dt_1.Load(R_1);

     TextBox_FormID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
     TextBox_FormID.AutoCompleteSource = dt_1 ;

     sc.Close();
 }
```

Is there any way to convert dt_1 to the type of autocomplete collection ? 
Or I should iterate the values into a new list and then add that list as a source?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349374/is-it-possible-to-make-a-datatable-as-a-autocompletesource-in-a-textbox-c)

```
string[] postSource = dt_1
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("MoM_ID"))
                    .ToArray();

var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(postSource);
  TextBox_FormID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
  TextBox_FormID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
  TextBox_FormID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you

Comment: So answer is: _You should iterate the values into a new list and then add that list as a source_